# compare 2 strings, subtract the same characters and return the new values

Tags: php, string, unique

i have two strings, it can be more then two may be 5 or 6

```
 $a =  2012-05-18 usr abc removed device id=858 sn=abc cmmac=000 drumac=123
 $b =  2012-05-18 usr abc removed device id=858 sn=abc cmmac=000 drumac=12352015-03-26 usr mabdel001c removed device id=814 sn=abcd cmmac=1234 drumac=000
```

i need help i need a function or any way that when i compare $a with $b it should only returns me string like below

```
$remaining = '2015-03-26 usr mabdel001c removed device id=814 sn=abcd cmmac=1234 drumac=000';
```

i tried this function with no luck `if (strcmp($var1, $var2) === 0) {`

Comment: Please note the rules to ask for help here: you are expected to do the job yourself, we are only here to help if you get stuck and need help with an issue you cannot solve yourself.

Comment: None of the start strings match the result string

Comment: @Andreas That is true, but that matches the OPs question.

Comment: why this is down voted ?

Comment: @arkascha so thats what i did, what else you want from me, i put all the explanation

Comment: You are expected to start programming, show an own attempt and post your code.

Comment: I did not downvote but am tempted. Because no effort is shown, and unclear question.

Comment: @arkascha what? I don't get it? What is it about OPs question. I don't get it...

Comment: I see it now. My bad.

Comment: @arkascha please be generous

Comment: @Naeem I am, I am! I am glad that you found someone to post code that apparently does what you are looking for. I myself help others here day in, day out. But to me it sounds questionable if people ask here apparently without having tried to solve their task themselves. That is not a good thing in my eyes. And that is why there are guidelines and rules here on SO. Anyway: as said: great that you got your issue solved! Have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use str_replace and replace with nothing:

```
$a =  "2012-05-18 usr abc removed device id=858 sn=abc cmmac=000 drumac=123";
$b =  "2012-05-18 usr abc removed device id=858 sn=abc cmmac=000 drumac=12352015-03-26 usr mabdel001c removed device id=814 sn=abcd cmmac=1234 drumac=000";

Echo str_replace($a, "", $b);
```

https://3v4l.org/KiZLN

Comment: I see that I was a bit late to the party. That is the downside of typing on the phone. The page does not update with new answers. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: Nah, it's fine. Similar answers are harmless, and sometimes people can benefit from seeing a slightly different explanation, IMO.

Answer (score 5):

It might not seem obvious the way you're thinking of it, but `str_replace` should work for this.

```
$remaining = str_replace($a, '', $b);
```

If `$a` is found in `$b` then `$remaining` will be `$b` with the characters of `$a` removed from it, otherwise `$remaining` will be the unchanged value of `$b`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach here would be to skip the matched content.

```
$a =  '2012-05-18 usr abc removed device id=858 sn=abc cmmac=000 drumac=123';
$b =  '2012-05-18 usr abc removed device id=858 sn=abc cmmac=000 drumac=12352015-03-26 usr mabdel001c removed device id=814 sn=abcd cmmac=1234 drumac=000';
if(strpos($b, $a) !== false) {
    echo substr($b, (strrpos($b, $a) + strlen($a)));
}
```

would work. If you have multiple matches though you will need a different approach (because this is only for 1 iteration). The `str_replace` is probably your best approach.

Demo: https://eval.in/829490